# OCaml: Global Module Binding

Tags: ocaml

I am working on a `OCaml` project, and I would like to declare some global bindings for external modules. For example:

```
module Test = struct

  open Another_module

  let module AM = Another_module 


  let func1 a =
     AM.process a

  let func2 a =
     AM.process a

end
```

However, when I compile some code organized as above, I always got a compile error for the global module binding sentence..

```
Parse error: "in" expected after [module_binding0] (in [str_item])
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of a module definition inside a structure is

```
module Name = module-expression
```

The keyword sequence `let module` is only used for a local binding of a module:

```
let module Name = module-expression in Name.x + Name.y
```

So you need to write

```
module Test = struct
  module AM = Another_module 
  let func1 a =
     AM.process a
end
```

Note that `module AM = Another_module` does not make the module names `AM` and `Another_module` completely interchangeable: they aren't equivalent when used in the argument to a functor, due to the way .